# Create adapter with dual horizontal items

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I've a listview with custom adapter with 2 custom layouts, it works perfectly, but the data has a trouble. The flow of data is only vertical, I need "change" the flow of data when the layout of adapter have 2 items, like this:

[image]

Any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

you could have a look into cardslib[1] - this offers such an option

[1] https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib

Comment: I need a lib for API 10

Comment: Cardslib doesn't have this feature :c Anyone can help?